# want to Pursue Phd in Philosophy?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

Want to pursue a PhD in Philosophy, but my Master degree is in Fine Arts (Painting). I want to know how likely will I be considered for the program? I have art history and Aesthetics, as my theory in Bfa and Ma.

Comment: Have you ever investigated any philosophical stuffs within that Painting degree, such as study of philosophical trends in different painting themes or something?... Actually, could you claim about the existence of any applied tendency toward philosophy within your latest degree?

Comment: In my dissertation I interviewed artists about their works,and what initiated them to pursue painting. one in particular have philosophical inclination, which is evident through his unique style.

Comment: Please approve the applied edit, if you confirm it...

Comment: @Matinking The OP has Masters is in Fine Arts. You seem to assume he has M.Sc (in your suggested edit).

Comment: @scaaahu: You are noticeably right... I just did correct the case... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above assertion truly postulates about the lack of appropriate trace for any ***effective and bold*** philosophical studies or research within your previous degree.

Composition of a coherent and powerful ***SoP*** sounds indispensable for you. You must pinpoint your motivation to switch from painting to philosophy, at first. Then, as Ph.D. studies and research in any field do need a robust background from the fundamental subjects, you could mention your self-studies within this territory to convince the admission committee upon your rather-structured mental background for pursing the new path.

In my estimation, the ***more functional approach*** would be digging into the other Master degree in philosophy, to construct your background in a fully-persuading fashion, and then taking the attempt into account for the Ph.D. admission.

Best of luck..

Comment: Will my writing sample be of any help in this aspect? or will it be dumped as my profile is unfit.

Comment: Your writing sample will, reasonably, neither augment nor deteriorate this aspect... Because it is just required due to assess your composing capabilities... Do send your best paper, in view of the syntax and semantic, as the writing sample and take care of your SoP for being sure to address your clarifications about the fitness of the philosophy program according to your case.

Comment: so, it is highly unlikely, but have a glim chance to be considered. Thank you @Matinking

Comment: Whole of the life is the grabbing of the chances... :)
Please do finalize the thread if the case has been resolved.